# Spring JPA caching - should I avoid retrieving the same resource from repository a few times?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a following line in my code:

```
String productName = Utils.getProductName(productId, productRepository, language);
```

This util method retrieves the product using method `findOne(productId)`, but has some additional logic well. It is used in multiple places in my code.

In one place, a few lines lower, I need the Product object, so I do following:

```
Product product = productRepository.findOne(productId);
```

Here I retrieve the Product again, so we have the same action on the database again. But **I believe that JPA (Hibernate) caches the object so I don't have to worry about it, the performance won't be affected**. Am I right?

*Of course, I try to avoid such a duplicity. But in this case refactoring `getProductName` method would have an impact on other places where I use this method. So I'd like to just leave it as it is. But if the performance cost would be noticeable, I'd better tweak the code.*

Comment: If both calls are made in the same transaction, yes, you're right. Why don't you turn on SQL logging and find out by yourself? It's always a good idea to have it turned on during development, especially when you don't understand Hibernate very well, so that you realize which queries it's executing.

Comment: I'm not experienced with JPA. Does the fact that the SQL query appears in the console mean that the object is retrieved again in the database, or still it may be cached and not really executed?

Comment: Hibernate logs SQL queries if it executes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a first level cache enabled on the entity manager. "In first level cache CRUD operations are performed per transaction basis to reduce the number of queries fired to the database."

http://www.developer.com/java/using-second-level-caching-in-a-jpa-application.html

Just be sure not to create "inconsistent" states without informing the entity manager or flush the changes to the DB.

Comment: thanks, that's an awesome link. But I'm not sure if it has to do with transactions, as I just retrieve resource without any modification. The quote that I find as key here is this one: `JPA entities are cached at the persistence context level and guarantees that there will be one object instance per persistence context for a specific row of a database table.` Which I understand in this way that Entity Manager will recognize that there is already an object with such ID cached and won't order JDBC to retrieve it again